# Remove end of line character, if another string is in the line (RegEx, Notepad++)

Tags: json, regex, notepad++

I have a JSON file, where I would like to remove the comma at the end of each line with the key `FullName` using Notepad++. I read about regular expressions and checked many forum questions without success.

```
{
  "Symbol": "BTC",
  "CoinName": "Bitcoin",
  "FullName": "Bitcoin (BTC)",
},
{
  "Symbol": "LTC",
  "CoinName": "Litecoin",
  "FullName": "Litecoin (LTC)",
},
{
  "Symbol": "XMR",
  "CoinName": "Monero",
  "FullName": "Monero (XMR)",
}
```

Comment: Search for `("FullName".*),`, replace with `$1`

Comment: Try [`(?<="FullName":)(.+),`](https://regex101.com/r/XurEfH/1)

Comment: Wow, you guys come up with a solution after 2mins where I searched for 2 hours. You are priceless! Thanks very much! But I feel stupid now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating that requirement into a regex isn't that hard. Just follow what you say:

```
^(\s*"FullName".*),
```

and replace it with `$1` (back-reference to first capturing group) or you can search for:

```
^\s*"FullName".*\K,
```

and replace it with nothing.

- `^` means assert start of line
- `\s*` any following space characters
- `.*` anything up to end of line
- `\K` reset match